SPO Setting default metadata per subfolder
We can set the column default values on a library at a subfolder level by going Library Settings -> Columns default value settings.
(ie here: https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/projectsite/_layouts/15/ColumnDefaults.aspx?List={641553e8-df1c-427b-a0d6-c7ade21dbfd8})
I'm looking at a project where I will need to set these folder-level defaults on 100's sites & 1000s libraries/folders.
I can find references to a 'MetadataDefaults' class in in the .NET API for old versions of SharePoint Server, but this appears to be deprecated or not available to SharePoint Online.
Question: Is it possible to set Folder-Level Column Defaults via some api/code?

The PnP.Framework does have an extension method for the CSOM List Class. I have not used this method but it does exists if you want to use C# code.
Code could be like this (field, ctx, and list are CSOM objects, folder is a string):
var defaultValue = field.GetDefaultColumnValueFromField(ctx, folder, new string[] { "value" });
list.SetDefaultColumnValues(new List<IDefaultColumnValue>() { defaultValue});

If you want to write a PowerShell Script you could use Set-PnPDEfaultColumnValues, which uses the PnP.Framework in the back.
